# GWT: Calling external JavaScript library (sjcl) method

Tags: javascript, gwt

I want to use an external crypto library in my GWT project (client side).  (particularly, Stanford Javascript Crypto Library, http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/
I have added these lines in my project's gwt configuration file (MyProj.gwt.xml)

```
<script src="libs/sjcl/sjcl.js" />
<script src="libs/sjcl/core/sha256.js" />
```

And have created a new method in my security class:

```
public static native String sha256(String ptext)
      /*-{
       return sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(ptext);
       }-*/;
```

But when I call it

```
String result = Security.sha256("password");
```

I get an error ("sjcl is not defined")

If someone who knows these issues and javasript could read the library and tell me the right way, I will be saving much time and effort - no digging in monstrous JavaScript.

UPD:

First thing I figured out, external library must be in /war directory
Second, I couldn't make GWT import the *.js files if I added the following just to gwt.xml files

```
<script src="libs/sjcl/sjcl.js"></script>
<script src="libs/sjcl/core/sha256.js"></script>
```

I had to add similar lines to Entry point's html source

```
<script src="/sjcl/sjcl.js"></script>
<script src="/sjcl/core/sha256.js"></script>
```

This way import works, I could check it with Chrome Inspector

I tried to use another library, not so complicated as sjcl, and it worked fine.
So, obviously, I'm not using sjcl right.
Another library is simpler, just pure methods, sjcl uses classes and stuff, but as I don't know JS at all, I can't figure out how to call such things properly without digging into JS syntax. I really would like to skip this part.

Can anybody look into the sjcl code and tell me how to call the method properly? The source is really small and JS pro can figure it out at a glance, I think.

UPD 2:
It turned out that adding the following code to gwt.xml is enough, just put library in /war and pay attention to the preceding "/" in the path. If you don't put it there, GWT will be seeking for you lib in module directory

UPD 3:
And don't forget to clear browser's cache or "not found" error won't go away

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that when you talk about objects in the global context that you prefix them with `$wnd`, meaning the main `window` instance that the app is running in. This is documented in the JSNI docs, see https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI#writing.

```
public static native String sha256(String ptext)
  /*-{
      return $wnd.sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(ptext);
  }-*/;
```

Comment: Colin, thanks! Added $wnd., that error disappeared but now another error occurs:

Comment: Fortunately, or unfortunately, this now means that there is no object called `sjcl` in the main window context. Make sure those script tags loaded (firebug, chrome inspector), and make sure some simple js-based version of what you are trying to build works before you make it all happen in GWT/Java.

Comment: Thanks! Edited the question as problem became clearer. Can you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

"sjcl is not defined" means that you didn't import the sjcl file correctly. 
Check the file path and make sure the browser can access the file.

Comment: Larry, I checked the path and changed it to the full one (like d:\...\sjcl.js), but the error still occurs