# Call js in java

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

how to call this library jsTimezoneDetect `https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect`function in gwt java client.  I had included it in html script, and must now call this

```
 var tz = jstz.determine();
tz.name();
```

my question is, how to call it in client gwt and send to client? Create a function that calls it like?:

```
static native void getTimeZone() /*-{
    var tz = jstz.determine(); 
        tz.name(); 
}-*/
```

Comment: You should really read [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239732/gwt-calling-external-javascript-library-sjcl-method).

Comment: You have the solution in your question. Just use `/*-{` and `}-*/`.

Comment: but i get is red yntax error: Native method do not specify a body

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling Javascript function of .js file from java GWT code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986462/calling-javascript-function-of-js-file-from-java-gwt-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close the native method with a semicolon:

```
native String method()/*-{
  // js code
  return tz.name();
}-*/;
```

Comment: thak you, i have one more question, how to assign this value now of client timezone to my String timeClient variable, wich i declare in another class for getting timestamp from db?